# Android Firebase app distribution - Service credentials file does not exist. Please check the service credentials path and try again

Tags: android, circleci, circleci-2.0, firebase-app-distribution

I'm trying to migrate from Crashlytics Beta to Firebase App Distribution.
CircleCi in the Middle.

The build failes in CircleCi with the following error:

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':FiverrApp:appDistributionUploadRelease'.
>     Service credentials file does not exist. Please check the service credentials path and try again

Here is how i'm configuring serviceCredentialsFile variable
In my build.gradle:

```
        release {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "FORCE_LOGS", "true"

        firebaseAppDistribution {
            releaseNotes="Notes\n" + getCommitMessages()
            groups="android-testers"
            serviceCredentialsFile="/api-project-xxx-yyy.json"
        }
    }
```

the file api-project-xxx-yyy.json is in the same folder with build.gradle file.
I've also tried:

```
serviceCredentialsFile="api-project-xxx-yyy.json"
serviceCredentialsFile='api-project-xxx-yyy.json'
```

And still no luck...
Would appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use `$rootDir` to get a path. For example if you pass you credentials file `api-project-xxx-yyy.json` to root directory than you can take it something like this:

```
    firebaseAppDistribution {
        ...
        serviceCredentialsFile="$rootDir/api-project-xxx-yyy.json"
    }
```

Comment: windows --> i have given full path still im getting error `> Service credentials file does not exist. Please check the service credentials path and try again`  got advice?

Comment: I have the same error with `rootDir` but when I log `System.out.println("serviceCredentialsFile: $rootDir/api-project-xxx-yyy.json")` I get the correct path...

Answer (score 3):

Try using a relative path instead:

```
serviceCredentialsFile = "./api-project-xxx-yyy.json"
```

Most likely your `api-project-xxx-yyy.json` is not in your root directory but you want to use the project's directory.

Comment: Still not working. I copied the file the parent directory, same error

Answer (score 0):

I use VS-Code. I right-clicked on the json file in Explorer, copied the path (the full path) and set it in build.gradle

serviceCredentialsFile= "path"

Answer (score -1):

Ended up doing the following:

```
    buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        firebaseAppDistribution {
            releaseNotes = "Notes\n" + getCommitMessages()
            groups = "android-testers"
            serviceCredentialsFile = "file.json"
        }
    }
}
```

file.json exist in:

- Main Folder

  - .idea
  - app
  - build
  - **file.json**

Comment: I tried this solution but it just gave me the same error message "Service credentials file does not exist. Please check the service credentials path and try again" Any other idea what causes this? Seems like it is looking in completely wrong place. It looks in my /.gradle/daemon/6.0.1/ path.

Comment: @Wox In my case it was related to granting permissions between firebase and the google cloud dashboard (Place where Firebase admin permission)