# Service credentials file does not exist. Please check the service credentials path and try again

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, build.gradle, firebase-app-distribution

i have followed this answer but i havent found didnt worked from answer --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/58777598/12553303

i have been trying to upload app upload to testers using app distribution using gradle method

still getting error :-----------

> Service credentials file does not exist. Please check the service credentials path and try again

[image]

i also went through the github issues https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/141
but  my json file already in that format  but giving the error

my gradle:--

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        firebaseAppDistribution {
            appId = "1:53200681765.........."

            serviceCredentialsFile = "C:/Users/Dell/GitProjects/xyzprojectname/app/googleservices.json"

            releaseNotesFile="C:/Users/Dell/GitProjects/xyzprojectname/app/esters.txt"
            testers="usercool@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

need help thanks

Comment: can you re-verify your service account json file path? 'C:/Users/Dell/GitProjects/xyzprojectname/app/googleservices.json' this one. Also check file name consistency as well

Comment: file consistency? @JeelVankhede?

Comment: fews sites says we should use absolute path rather than relative?

Comment: I mean check for spelling mistakes in file path or file name.

Comment: Since you're on Windows Os *(as I can see C drive in filepath)*, I can take a note that you're using backward slashes '/' while windows file paths are constructed using forward slashes '\\' one extra required to skip token in string, try that once.